# Memory leak problem using withNavigationFocus in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, asynchronous, memory-leaks, listener

I have a listener set up using `withNavigationFocus` so that every time the user arrives on a screen or leaves the screen, a certain event gets triggered.  But, I'm getting the following error:

> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.
>   This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application.
>   To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks

```
const PleaseSignIn = props => {
    const {
        state: { authOpen },
        authModal
    } = useContext(Context)

    const focusListener = props.navigation.addListener('didFocus', () => {
        retrieveToken()     
    })

    const retrieveToken = async () => {
        try {
            const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem(LOGIN_TOKEN)
            if(!token) {
                authModal()
            }
        } catch (err) {
            throw new Error(err)
        }
    }

    if(!authOpen) {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}> 
                <Auth navigation={props.navigation} />
                <Signup navigation={props.navigation}  />
                <Signin navigation={props.navigation} />
            </View>
        )
    }
    return props.children
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
    }
})

export default withNavigationFocus(PleaseSignIn)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After setting up an event listener, we must also stop listening to the event when the screen is unmounted. 
You have functional component  and can subscribe and unsubscribe by using hook.
Something like this:

```
 useEffect(() => {
 const focusListener = 
 props.navigation.addListener('didFocus', async() => {
      await retrieveToken();     
      });

   // returned function will be called on component 
    //unmount 
   return () => {
    focusListener.remove();
   }
   }, []);
```